# Does redis-py object have to be made global variable to use in function?

Tags: python, function, object, redis, pickle

I am using redis-py as follows to store an object:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)


def store_object(key, obj):
    var = pickle.dumps(obj)
    r.set(key, var)


def restore_object(key):
    obj = pickle.loads(r.get(key))
    return obj


store_object('model', Object())
```

and then retrieving the object in a different function:

```
def function():
        print(restore_object('model'))
```

which prints "None". Do I need to make the restored object a global variable or something (The whole reason I was using Redis was to avoid this)?

Just doing (not in a function):

```
store_object('model', Object())
print(restore_object('model'))
```

displays the correct object.

Also, passing parameter to function is not an option

Answer (score 0):

You are using both pickle and Redis, which seems redundant. The whole point of Redis is to be able to store/get values stored in memory without having to deal with overhead.
What I think you want to do is:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r.set('a',1) # Setting a value which is stored in memory
... some code later
r.get('a') # Get said value(s)
```

No need for auxiliary functions or pickle

Comment: It was my understanding this did not work with objects though?

Comment: Also I would have the same problem regardless of whether or not Im using pickle